# problem with click in menu JS with Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I have a problem for select link in JS from primefaces.

I try with multiple ideas from StackOverflow but that no works.

For example:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Inscripción")).click();
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='Inscripción']").click();
```

The code HTML from menu when I need click is this:

```
<li class="submenu"><a id="j_idt53:j_idt63:0:j_idt65" href="#" class="ui-commandlink ui-widget" onclick="PrimeFaces.addSubmitParam('j_idt53',{'j_idt53:j_idt63:0:j_idt65':'j_idt53:j_idt63:0:j_idt65'}).submit('j_idt53');return false;">Inscripción</a></li>
```

Comment: href is `href="#"` , so manually also it should not be clicked. Are you able to click on it?

Comment: Yeah click with mouse works